# How would you solve after two variables in a two line equation system (containing trigonometric functions)?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I currently use two variables $x_p$ and $y_p$ to calculate two new coordinates $x_n$ and $y_n$. My question is now, could you solve after $x_p$ and $y_p$ somehow? I dont know how to do it.

$x_n=x_c + \sin(-2\pi\cdot\frac{x_p-x_c}{W}+\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot y_p$

$y_n=\cos(-2\pi\cdot\frac{x_p-x_c}{W}+\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot y_p$

Comment: $$ y_p^2=(x_n-x_c)^2 +y_n^2 $$

Comment: Could you please add a short explanation, how does the pythagorean theorem help here? And dont you have to account for $W$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $\theta \equiv -2\pi\cdot\frac{x_p-x_c}{W}+\frac{\pi}{2} $

then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
y_p \sin\theta&=&x_n-x_c
\\y_p \cos\theta&=&y_n
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Square both equations and sum the result

$$y_p^2=y_P^2\sin^2\theta+ y_P^2\cos^2\theta=(x_n-x_c)^2+y_n^2$$

Then $$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{y_n}{y_p} \right) $$

and

$$ x_p = -\frac W{2\pi}\left( \theta-\frac\pi 2 \right)+x_c $$

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Comment: When thinking about it, shouldnt $\cos^{-1}(\cfrac{y_p}{y_n})$ be $\cos^{-1}(\cfrac{y_n}{y_p})$? Also, is there any way you can get $x_p$ on one side without it being on the other side?

Comment: Thanks - I have corrected the $y_p, y_n$ mix up . As for the $x_p$ thing, I'm not sure what you are seeing, I only see $x_p$ on one side of my final equation - I hope I am correct in treating $x_c$ as a constant.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I was confused, should work now, thanks. And yes $x_c$ is a constant.